# OpenCV apply my own filter to a color image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working in OpenCV C++ to filtering image color. I want to filter the image using my own matrix. See this code:

```
img= "c:/Test/tes.jpg";
Mat im = imread(img);
```

And then i want to filtering/multiply with my matrix (this matrix can replaced with another matrix 3x3)

```
Mat filter = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) <<17.8824, 43.5161, 4.11935, 
                                   3.45565, 27.1554, 3.86714, 
                                   0.0299566, 0.184309, 1.46709);
```

How to multiply the `img` mat matrix with my own matrix? I'm still not understand how to multiply 3 channel (RGB) matrix with another matrix (single channel) and resulted image with new color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should take a look at the [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d). You could use this function:

```
filter2D(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int ddepth, InputArray kernel, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1), double delta=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT )
```

which would give you something like this in your code:

```
Mat output;
filter2D(im, output, -1, filter);
```

About your question for 3-channel matrix; it is specified in the documentation:

```
kernel – convolution kernel (or rather a correlation kernel), a single-channel floating point matrix; if you want to apply different kernels to different channels, split the image into separate color planes using split() and process them individually.
```

So by default your "filter" matrix will be applied equally to each color plane.

**EDIT** You find a fully functional example on the opencv site: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have found an algorithm in MatLab to solve that.First we must get every single pixel in R,G,and B matrix.For example, get the pixel value from (row,col) (1,1)R,(1,1)G,(1,1)B,next create mat 3x1 matrix and multiplied with my own matrix which produce new 3x1 matrix.And then put every element of the new matrix into new RGB matrix (1,1)R->new value,(1,1)B->new value, and so on.But i don't have idea to do that in C++.

Comment: why would you rewrite that yourself? just use the function provided by opencv since you are using opencv...

Comment: @ChrisMaes The docs state that Kernels can be of sizes 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11. But I have a matrix of 5 * 4.
For example:

const _FILTER_2 = [
  0.4, 0.4, -0.3, 0.0, 1.0, //
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, //
  0.0, 0.0, 1.2, 0.0, 1.0, //
  -1.2, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0
];

Do you maybe know how to apply such a matrix with filter2D?

Comment: @goldensoju it's been a while since I used openCV. Also this seems like a more specific question. Consider posting it as a new question.